# update bower.json with new versions

Tags: json, bower, frontend

I have a couple of dependicies in my bower.json and I would like to update the packages to the latest so I run `bower update` and it doesnt change my bower.json with new versions. I also tried `bower update signalr --save` but it still didn't change bower.json.

Why is that? Do I manually have to change bower.json? How is it possible to know what versions that are used?

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "~1.4.2",
"angular-bootstrap": "^1.2.5",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"signalr": "^2.2.0",
"toastr": "^2.1.2",
"angular-i18n": "~1.5.0",
"angular-route": "^1.5.2",
"angular-animate": "^1.5.2",
"angular-cookies": "^1.5.2",
"angular-hotkeys": "cfp-angular-hotkeys#^1.7.0",
"bootswatch": "^3.3.6",
"dirPagination": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update `bower.json` running the `bower install some-package --save` again and ***selecting the version*** to which you want to upgrade from terminal, as:

```
$ bower install signalr --save      
bower signalr#*                 cached https://github.com/SignalR/bower-signalr.git#2.2.1
bower signalr#*               validate 2.2.1 against https://github.com/SignalR/bower-signalr.git#*

Unable to find a suitable version for signalr, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) signalr#2.2.0 which resolved to 2.2.0 and is required by bower-example
    2) signalr#^2.2.1 which resolved to 2.2.1

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2
bower signalr#^2.2.1           install signalr#2.2.1

signalr#2.2.1 bower_components/signalr
└── jquery#3.1.1
```